# Xpath in xsd schema

Tags: xml

I would like `name3` array to include the documentation text of the ascendant element `<xsd:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="tns:PurchaseOrderType"/>`. I would like to have a generic code which prints the doccumentation according to the name of the xsd:element.

I have succeeded to include all the documentations using the xpath I provided. But I want the extra condition I mentioned to be included in the xpath.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="tns:PurchaseOrderType"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
         <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                commmennttt
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ShipTo" type="tns:USAddress" maxOccurs="2"/>
   <xsd:element name="BillTo" type="tns:USAddress"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="OrderDate" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="city"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="state"  type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="zip"    type="xsd:integer"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>

t3 = etree.ElementTree(file='new.xsd')
name3 = t3.xpath("//xsd:documentation[text()]", namespaces={"xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"})
name3 = [a.text for a in name3]
print(name3[0])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the `xsd:element` by criteria and then by next sibling containg a `xsd:documentation` descendant.

```
from lxml import etree
crit = 'PurchaseOrder'
t3 = etree.parse('test.xsd')
ns = {"xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"}
xpathExpr=f"//xsd:element[@name='{crit}']/following-sibling::*//xsd:documentation[text()]"
print(xpathExpr)
name3 = t3.xpath(xpathExpr, namespaces=ns)

# avoid reusing a variable for a different purpose
comments = [a.text for a in name3]
print(comments)
```

Result

```
//xsd:element[@name='PurchaseOrder']/following-sibling::*//xsd:documentation[text()]
['\n                commmennttt\n            ']
```

Comment: What library are you using? my code isn't recognizing this line doc.xpath('...

Comment: lxml, added the import to the answer. Should be t3.xpath() in your code. Sorry, missed a line of code.

Comment: lxml, added the import to the answer. Should be t3.xpath() in your code. Sorry, missed a line of code.

Comment: it's printing an empty array.

Comment: you tested it?!

Comment: Of course. Used the xsd sample in the question. python3.

Comment: it worked when I replaced crit variable with 'OrderPurchase'. that's weird:/

Comment: Sample shows `PurchaseOrder`

Comment: I meant PurchaseOrder sorry

Answer (score 0):

Finding information in an XML document, whether it's a schema or anything else, means that you need to know what invariants you can rely on. If this could be any valid schema at all then your task is very difficult (especially if it uses xs:include and xs:import). If it's never going to change at all, then you don't need to access it at all, because you already know what's there. In between those extremes, you need a clear idea of what's going to stay the same and what might change. We can't work that out from one specimen document. If it's only the comment that will change, then you can use an approach like that in @LMC's answer. If more radical changes might arise, then this approach will break down. Accessing a schema using an API to the compiled schema, rather than XPath expressions to access the source XSD files, is generally to be preferred.